# PHP Store processed file

Tags: php, file, caching

I want to make a caching system, and I need way to store result after PHP processed file (static HTML/XNL/JSON, whatever).

Is there some function to get result after processed file?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `ob_start()` function native php. see php documentation, how to use it.